# Move files after importing into Access DB

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba

I'm developing a VB macro in Access to import CSV files into an Access database and I would like move these files once the treatment is completed.

```vb
Public Sub RepertoireList()

Dim FolderName As String
Dim FolderNameMove As String
Dim FileList As String
Dim FileListMove As String
Dim FileToBeLoaded As String

tblName = "tbl_Test" 'This is to import all files into one table.
FolderName = "c:\CSV\"
FolderNameMove = "c:\CSV\Old"
FileList = Dir(FolderName & "\*.csv")
FileListMove = Dir(FolderNameMove & "\*.csv")

While (Len(Trim$(FileList)) > 0)        

    If (Len(Trim$(FileList))) > 0 Then
        FileToBeLoaded = FolderName & FileList
        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Test2 Import Specification", tblName, FileToBeLoaded, False

    End If
    FileList = Dir

    'Move files after import
    Sub Deplacer()
         Dim FSO As Object
         Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
         FSO.MoveFile Source:=FolderName, Destination:=FolderNameMove
    End Sub       

Wend    

End Sub
```

The import works correctly but moving files isn't done correctly.

Comment: if it has macros, it aint VB.NET

Comment: Do not use tags not pertinent to your question. VB,NET is not VBA

Comment: And the method for move files isn't good ?

Comment: Yes sorry for the tag, it's an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim FolderName As String
Dim FileList As String
Dim FileToBeLoaded As String

tblName = "CV_Test" 'This is to import all files into one table.
FolderName = "c:\CSV\"
FolderNameMove = "c:\CSV\Old\"
FileList = Dir(FolderName & "\*.csv")

While (Len(Trim$(FileList)) > 0)
    If (Len(Trim$(FileList))) > 0 Then
        FileToBeLoaded = FolderName & FileList
        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Test2 Import Specification", tblName, FileToBeLoaded, False
    End If
    FileList = Dir
Wend

'Move files after import
FileList = Dir(FolderName & "\*.csv")
While (Len(Trim$(FileList)) > 0)
    If (Len(Trim$(FileList))) > 0 Then
        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        FSO.MoveFile Source:=FolderName & FileList, Destination:=FolderNameMove
    End If
    FileList = Dir

Wend
```

Comment: This answer is not sufficient. In addition to providing a solution in code, you need to explain *why* it works.